# API access to new disk IO and bandwidth metric in azure

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm looking for API access to the [newly created metrics in azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/new-disk-io-and-bandwidth-metrics-to-identify-bottlenecks/). I couldn't find API access related to that.

Comment: Is that you want to know how to use rest API to get Azure VM metrics?

Comment: If you want to get azure vm metrics, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metrics/list

Comment: @JimXu I highlighted the page where the API is mentioned in question that wasn't visible before. Here for reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/new-disk-io-and-bandwidth-metrics-to-identify-bottlenecks/ 

I'm looking for API access to this metrics.